# Illustrated science fiction story about a astronaut infected with an alien symbiote

Tags: story-identification, aliens, symbiotes

I read a science fiction story around the year 2000.  The story was accompanied by large illustrations, and the book itself was large, bigger than a novel or trade paperback.  It was about an astronaut visiting a fellow astronaut at a country house.  The two men had been friends before the infection happened. The astronaut living at the house had been infected with a symbiotic alien that was a risk to world security.  I got the impression the infection had occurred on an off-world mission.  The visiting astronaut arrived in a car that had a hydrogen bomb aboard, perhaps hidden in one of the tires.  The two astronauts played a game of cat and mouse; the visiting astronaut was prepared to detonate the bomb and exterminate the infected astronaut.  In one of the illustrations, the infected astronaut was sitting behind a desk and appendages of the symbiote formed a  spoke-like pattern around and above his head.  I don't remember how the story ended.

Comment: The plot reminds me of a Philip K. Dick short story I read once where one of the characters didn't know he had a planet destroying bomb inside him.  So the illustrated story could have been an adaptation of a Philip K. Dick story, although the examples here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_K._Dick#Comics. don't seem likely.